# Issue with json parsing using retrofit-Android

Tags: android

I am facing a problem to parse json response using the class file in Android. I am getting the error like "problem during conversion".Anyone can tell me what is the error in the code? I am giving my nested class here along with the response.

```
public class SendCouponCode {
int statusCode;
boolean status;
String message;
boolean furtherActionNeeded;
ArrayList<Extras> extra;

public void setExtra(ArrayList<Extras> extra) {
    this.extra = extra;
}

public class Extras{
    String nextAction;
    String nextActionTitle;
    ArrayList<Item> items;

    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getNextAction() {
        return nextAction;
    }

    public void setNextAction(String nextAction) {
        this.nextAction = nextAction;
    }

    public String getNextActionTitle() {
        return nextActionTitle;
    }

    public void setNextActionTitle(String nextActionTitle) {
        this.nextActionTitle = nextActionTitle;
    }

    public class Item{
        int id;
        String value;
        boolean isExclusive;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public boolean isExclusive() {
            return isExclusive;
        }

        public void setExclusive(boolean exclusive) {
            isExclusive = exclusive;
        }
    }
}
public int getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public boolean isFurtherActionNeeded() {
    return furtherActionNeeded;
}

public void setFurtherActionNeeded(boolean furtherActionNeeded) {
    this.furtherActionNeeded = furtherActionNeeded;
}}
```

And,the response which i am parsing is

```
 {
   "further_action_needed": true,
   "status": true,
   "message": "Coupon code is being processed, further action is needed for completion.",
   "status_code": 901,
   "extra": {
  "items": [
  {
    "is_exclusive": false,
    "id": 7,
    "name": "XXX"
  },
  {
    "is_exclusive": false,
    "id": 8,
    "name": "XXX"
  },
  {
    "is_exclusive": false,
    "id": 9,
    "name": "XX"
  },
  {
    "is_exclusive": false,
    "id": 21,
    "name": "XX"
  },
  {
    "is_exclusive": false,
    "id": 26,
    "name": "Default Batch"
  },
  {
    "is_exclusive": false,
    "id": 57,
    "name": "XX"
  },
  {
    "is_exclusive": false,
    "id": 63,
    "name": "XX"
  }
],
"next_action_title": "Select Your Batches",
"next_action": "ADD_BATCHES"  }}
```

My GSon Builder class uses this field

```
 Gson gson = new   GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
```

And my error log is

```
   me.entri.entrime.beans.EntriError: Something went wrong internally.        Please consider reporting the issue to us.
  03-02 16:43:41.431 28965-28965/me.entri.entrime W/System.err:     at       retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:383)
  03-02 16:43:41.431 28965-28965/me.entri.entrime W/System.err:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
 03-02 16:43:41.432 28965-28965/me.entri.entrime W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
 03-02 16:43:41.432 28965-28965/me.entri.entrime W/System.err:     at $Proxy2.sendCoupon(Unknown Source)
 03-02 16:43:41.432 28965-28965/me.entri.entrime W/System.err:     at me.entri.entrime.api.GeneralApiService.sendCouponCode(GeneralApiService.java:786)
 03-02 16:43:41.432 28965-28965/me.entri.entrime W/System.err:     at me.entri.entrime.api.GeneralApiService.onHandleIntent(GeneralApiService.java:339)
   03-02 16:43:41.432 28965-28965/me.entri.entrime W/System.err:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
     03-02 16:43:41.432 28965-28965/me.entri.entrime W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 03-02 16:43:41.432 28965-28965/me.entri.entrime W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  03-02 16:43:41.432 28965-28965/me.entri.entrime W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Retrofit can't instantiate the instance of Extras and Item without SendCouponCode instance. I would try to make all nested classes static. Please, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Inner classes cannot have static blocks

Comment: if class A contains inner static class B then B can have static inner class C.

Comment: @AlexandrKarpovich i am getting the response by calling the api. But the problem lies where the json conversion happens. So thats why I provided these details. I am sure that error is in this proccess only. Please review my question again.

Comment: please post your error log

Comment: @CoDFather please check the question again

Comment: Also try to use @SerializedName annotation. For example, in your class:

@SerializedName("status_code")
int statusCode;

SerializedName should match to the json field name

Answer (score 0):

Use below model to parse

```
public class SendCouponCode {

@SerializedName("further_action_needed")
@Expose
private Boolean furtherActionNeeded;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Boolean status;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("status_code")
@Expose
private Integer statusCode;
@SerializedName("extra")
@Expose
private Extra extra;

public Boolean getFurtherActionNeeded() {
return furtherActionNeeded;
}

public void setFurtherActionNeeded(Boolean furtherActionNeeded) {
this.furtherActionNeeded = furtherActionNeeded;
}

public Boolean getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public Integer getStatusCode() {
return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public Extra getExtra() {
return extra;
}

public void setExtra(Extra extra) {
this.extra = extra;
}

}
```

Comment: I am using field naming policy in my API manager config. So those annotations are not required

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 classes like this

SendCouponCode.class

```
public class SendCouponCode {


private Boolean furtherActionNeeded;

private Boolean status;

private String message;

private Integer statusCode;

private Extra extra;

public Boolean getFurtherActionNeeded() {
return furtherActionNeeded;
}

public void setFurtherActionNeeded(Boolean furtherActionNeeded) {
this.furtherActionNeeded = furtherActionNeeded;
}

public Boolean getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public Integer getStatusCode() {
return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public Extra getExtra() {
return extra;
}

public void setExtra(Extra extra) {
this.extra = extra;
}

}
```

Extra.class

```
public class Extra {


private List<Item> items = null;

private String nextActionTitle;

private String nextAction;

public List<Item> getItems() {
return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
this.items = items;
}

public String getNextActionTitle() {
return nextActionTitle;
}

public void setNextActionTitle(String nextActionTitle) {
this.nextActionTitle = nextActionTitle;
}

public String getNextAction() {
return nextAction;
}

public void setNextAction(String nextAction) {
this.nextAction = nextAction;
}

}
```

Item.class

```
public class Item {


private Boolean isExclusive;

private Integer id;

private String name;

public Boolean getIsExclusive() {
return isExclusive;
}

public void setIsExclusive(Boolean isExclusive) {
this.isExclusive = isExclusive;
}

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

you can do it by [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

Comment: I am using fieldnaming policy. So why should i use serialisation nottation again?

Comment: You can just remove it and try adding seperate classes